# Can I say $\sum^{M}_{k=0} \binom{n}{k} = O(n^M)\;$? And is there a tighter asymptotic bound?

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

Can I say the following?

$$\sum^{M}_{k=0} \binom{n}{k} = O(n^M)$$

Assuming that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a variable and $M \in \mathbb{N}$ is a constant.

Can I obtain a tighter asymptotic bound for this sum?

Comment: Since $\sum_{k=0}^M \binom{n}{k} \ge \binom{n}{M}\ge (n-M)^M/M!$, and the latter also grows like $n^M$, your bound is optimal.

Answer (score 3):

One has

$$  \frac{n^k}{k^k} \le \binom{n}{k} \le \frac{n^k}{k!} $$

Now

$$  \sum_{k=0}^M  \frac{n^k}{k!} \le n^M\sum_{k=0}^M \frac{1}{k!} \le  n^M \,e$$

And $$\sum_{k=0}^M  \frac{n^k}{k^k} \ge  \frac{n^M}{M^M}$$

Hence, indeed,  $$\frac{1}{M^M} n^M  \le  \sum_{k=0}^M \binom{n}{k}  \le e\, n^M $$

More concretely, one [can show that](https://mathoverflow.net/a/17236) $$ \sum_{k=0}^M \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{M}(1 + O(1/n))$$
(the last term dominates) and
$$ \binom{n}{M} = \frac{1}{M!}{n^M}(1 + O(1/n))  $$

Hence
$$ \sum_{k=0}^M \binom{n}{k}  = \frac{1}{M!}{n^M}(1 + O(1/n))  $$